# New to PHP logins and sessions; Is this safe enough?

Tags: php, security, session, browser, cookies

I have a classifieds website which I am creating a login system for...

In the code below, a form with "username" and "password" has been submitted to. Also a "remember_me" feature is available (Code is not tested yet):

```
else if($row['password']===$pass){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = '1';
    $remember_me = isset($_POST['remember']) ? $_POST['remember'] : '0';
    if($remember_me=='1'){

        $text = "SECRET_TEXT_AND_NUMBERS_HERE";
        $username= $row['username'];

        $salt1 = sha1($row['alt_username']);
        $salt2 = sha1($text);

        $cookie_value = $salt1.':'.$username.':'.sha1($row['alt_username'].$salt2.$salt1);

        setcookie("s_b", $cookie_value, time()+60*60*24*100, "/");

    }

}
```

Now, is this code a good start for a login page?

Also, an important follow-up question to all this, if users want to stay logged in, do I then set a `$_SESSION` variable like the one in the code, and just check if that is set in the beginning of all pages on the site?

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) // Then user is logged in already
```

or do I check to see if the cookie created in the login page is set instead of checking the session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

logging in is about security; security is always more difficult then it seems.

There are a couple of things that you could improve in your code. first:

the security for your password is in the strength of the hasing algorithm. You choose to use `sha1` (better than md5, but could be improved by using sha256 or bCrypt if you use PHP version >= 5.3)

**First**
The salt you use is supposed to be a random value, stored alongside the hashed result.
in other words, the value to store in your database is:

```
$salt = [some random string of predifend lenght]; // Let's say 16 characters in length
$storedValue = $salt . sha256($salt . $password);
```

you check the password:

```
if ($row['username'] == $_POST['username']  && substr($row['$storedValue'], 16) == sha256(substr($row['$storedValue'], 0, 16) . $_POST['password'])) {
    // login ok
} else {
    // login fail
}
```

**(better yet)**
Use a proven library for the password hashing stuff, take a look at: [Portable PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) and try to use the CRYPT_BLOWFISH algorithm if at all popssible.

**Second**
You should only store the session key in the session cookie. all other information is stored on the server.
The session cookie is already send out by PHP's session_start() function call, so you do not have to worry about this anymore.

if you want to check the sessions lifetime, you should store this information in the session array:

```
$_SESSION['lastActivity'] =  time()+60*60*24*100;
```

**Third**
The remember me token is a 'password equivalent' so you should only store a hash of the token in your database, just treat it as a password, only this 'password' is not typed by the user, but read from the cookie.

Comment: Could you explain "Store the session key in the session cookie" part? Shouldn't I store a cookie like I am in the code I posted? Examples are much appreciated?

Comment: session_start() sets a cookie containing a session key, you do not need to set any other cookie to store information. If you want to store information for this user, you can do so in `$_SESSION`

Comment: Yes, during sessions offcourse I wont use cookies. But I meant the "Remember me" feature. Another thing I thought about was, is only a session variable enough for making sure the user is logged in? Is there any other barriers I could add to make it even more secure when users are switching between pages, instead of just checking one "session variable to be true or false"?

Comment: For the remember me function, you should read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-website-authentication#477579

Comment: Generally speaking, you can consider a user to be logged in when they have a valid session cookie. It is considered good practice however to limit the time the session remains valid for to 30 minutes or so. You want the cookie to be a 'session-cookie' (=kept until browser close) and the time-out check to be done on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a hash is that its non-reversible, so it's not really adding any value the way you've used for the remember me function. Stop pretending it does anything useful, and use a random token for the remember me (and log this in the database against the username) then, if you get a client presenting a remember me cookie without an authenticated session, you know where to look to find out who it is.

(this also allows a sensible approach to be applied where the user keeps moving to different machines - you might say keep the last 2 values - and flag when they try to remember me from a 3rd machine).

A 100 day timeout is rather long - maybe 30 days (with an automatic refresh might be more appropriate depending on the level of risk.